# NSData to [Uint8] in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdata

I couldn't find a solution to this problem in Swift (all of them are Objective-C, and they deal with pointers which I don't think exist in Swift in the same form). Is there any way to convert a `NSData` object into an array of bytes in the form of `[Uint8]` in Swift?

Answer (score 128):

You can avoid first initialising the array to placeholder values, if you go through pointers in a slightly convoluted manner, or via the new `Array` constructor introduced in Swift 3:

#### Swift 3

```
let data = "foo".data(using: .utf8)!

// new constructor:
let array = [UInt8](data)

// …or old style through pointers:
let array = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    [UInt8](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: data.count))
}
```

#### Swift 2

```
Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), count: data.length))
```

Comment: Though clean and convenient, this uses an NSArray and may cause errors down the road...

Comment: @califrench I'm sorry, I didn't follow. 1) There is no `NSArray` that I can spot, the `bytes` accessor does not return it. 2) What errors would it cause down the road? If you're referring to possible unavailability of `NS*` classes, recall that the question specifies `NSData`.

Comment: I'm sorry @Arkku, I got confused, I was thinking for a minute that `Array()` was relying on `NSArray` but I don't think it is...
The issues down the road would have been trying to access an element using a subscript since `NSArray`s don't know what kind of elements they contain whereas Swift `Array`s do.

Comment: This fails with a compiler error. `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer<Void>)'`

Comment: @Dan It works just fine for me both in Swift 2.2 and Swift 3. In Swift 3 the preceding line is `let data : NSData! = "foo".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)`

Comment: @Arkku it doesn't compile with latest Swift, I had to change it to: array = data.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in Array( UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes, count: data.count) ) }

Comment: @Zmey: True, it stopped working at some point during the XCode 8 betas. I've updated the answer with that solution, thanks!

Comment: Data conforms to MutableCollection in Swift 3 so you can initialize an Array with it to get an array of UInt8. try `Array(data)`

Comment: @LeoDabus That's basically a different way of saying `[UInt8](data)`, which is already in the answer since the latest edit. (And IMO the clearer syntax with explicit type.)

Comment: how to get signed bytes here?

Answer (score 79):

**Swift 5 Solution**

Data to [bytes]

```
extension Data {
    var bytes: [UInt8] {
        return [UInt8](self)
    }
}
```

[bytes] to Data

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {
    var data: Data {
        return Data(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Data(bytes:(self)) is deprecated in Swift 5 :'(

Comment: great answer, elegant af

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly question, but this would produce a copy, right?

Comment: @TobiSchweiger yes because arrays are always value types in Swift, so arrays always copy

Answer (score 49):

It's funny but exist more simple solution. Works in Swift 3. Surely. I've used this today.

```
data: Data // as function parameter    
let byteArray = [UInt8](data)
```

That's all! :)
NSData easily bridged to Data.

**UPDATE:** (due to Andrew Koster comment)

**Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3.1**

Just has been rechecked - all works as expected.

```
if let nsData = NSData(base64Encoded: "VGVzdFN0cmluZw==", options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
let bytes = [UInt8](nsData as Data)
print(bytes, String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8))
```

**Output:** [84, 101, 115, 116, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103] Optional("TestString")

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, now that Swift 3 is out.

Comment: This most likely makes a copy of your data. While small, not a big deal. If large, can cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `getBytes` function of `NSData` to get the byte array equivalent.

As you did not provide any source code, I will use a Swift String contents that has been converted to NSData.

```
var string = "Hello World"
let data : NSData! = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt8)

// create an array of Uint8
var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

// copy bytes into array
data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))

println(array)
```

**Swift 3/4**

```
let count = data.length / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

// create an array of Uint8
var byteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
// copy bytes into array
data.getBytes(&byteArray, length:count)
```

Comment: For swift 3 replace sizeof(UInt8) with MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3/4**

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x01, 0x02, 0x03])
let byteArray: [UInt8] = data.map { $0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4 and image data to a byte array.

```
 func getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData:Data) ->[UInt8]{

    let count = imageData.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
    var byteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
    imageData.copyBytes(to: &byteArray, count:count)
    return byteArray

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
extension Data {
func toByteArray() -> [UInt8]? {
    var byteData = [UInt8](repeating:0, count: self.count)
    self.copyBytes(to: &byteData, count: self.count)
    return byteData
  }
}
```