# Swift convert from OBJC

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

i build camera app from this guide : https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/index.html
and write averything in swift .
Can someone help to convert this to swift ?

```
-(void)videoFeed:(DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData:(NSData *)videoData {
    [[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] push:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length];
}
```

when i convert this to swift like this :

```
func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData videoData: Data) {
        DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().push(UInt8(videoData?.bytes ?? 0), length: (videoData?.count ?? 0))
    }
```

i got errors:

**Cannot convert value of type 'UInt8' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'Int?'**

Please help.

Comment: `videoData?`, why the "?" here? It doesn't seem unwrapped. So `(videoData?.count ?? 0)` should be `videoData.count`, `(videoData?.bytes ?? 0)` should be `videoData.bytes`,  For the rest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821709/nsdata-to-uint8-in-swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use official code samples [GitHub](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/blob/master)

[Right here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/blob/master/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode/DJISDKSwiftDemo/Camera/VideoPreviewerAdapter.swift)

```
    func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData videoData: Data) {
        guard videoFeed == feed else {
            NSLog("ERROR: Wrong video feed update is received!");
            return
        }
        videoData.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(mutating: ptr)
            previewer?.push(p, length: Int32(videoData.count))
            
        }
    }
```

try to search a bit better before deleting posts next time