# Objective-C to Swift conversion question for bytes

Tags: swift, objective-c, pointers, byte

I have a very old Objective-C app that I am trying to convert to Swift. I am not well versed in Objective-C and even less so in pointers.
I have this code here that I can not figure out what to do with:

```
NSData *ucTimeData=[self getUcTime];
Byte *ucTimeByte = (Byte *)[ucTimeData bytes];
```

The `NSData` looks like this when printing the description:

```
Printing description of data:
<9ea49c1d>
```

What would be the Swift equivalent of the `Byte` conversion? `ucTimeData.bytes` returns an unsafe pointer so something like:

```
let ucTimeByte: UInt8 = UInt8(ucTimeData.bytes)
```

which I guess would be the literal translation but it does not work.

Comment: Without knowing how you're going to _use_ those bytes, it's hard to give a good recommendation here.

Comment: General rule is it's a bad idea to convert from ObjC to Swift line by line. It's not always beneficial to even convert a single function. In many cases you need to look at a bigger picture: which inputs you need to handle, which outputs you expect, and are there Swift libraries that already handle what previously was done by hand. This especially applies to pointers - there's almost no reasons to use them in Swift. So please provide more context on what you are converting, and what are the inputs, and expected outputs

Comment: Seems that that your data contains an array of bytes. utcTimeBute is a pointer to an array of uint8 aka bytes. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821709/nsdata-to-uint8-in-swift)